# Руководство по Canvas из HTML5

Tags: canvas, javascript, html5

Кто-нибудь встречал понятное руководство по использованию canvas из html5. Попробовал некоторые примеры, вроде, всё получается, но понимания не получил.

**UPD1:** Как раз выборочно читал это. Кусок google mail checker'a:

```
function animateFlip() {
  rotation += 1/animationFrames;
  drawIconAtRotation();

  if (rotation <= 1) {
    setTimeout("animateFlip()", animationSpeed);
  } else {
    rotation = 0;
    drawIconAtRotation();
    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({color:[208, 0, 24, 255]});
  }
}
function ease(x) {
  return (1-Math.sin(Math.PI/2+x*Math.PI))/2;
}
function drawIconAtRotation() {
  canvasContext.save();
  canvasContext.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  canvasContext.translate(
      Math.ceil(canvas.width/2),
      Math.ceil(canvas.height/2));
  canvasContext.rotate(2*Math.PI*ease(rotation));
  canvasContext.drawImage(loggedInImage,
      -Math.ceil(canvas.width/2),
      -Math.ceil(canvas.height/2));
  canvasContext.restore();

  chrome.browserAction.setIcon({imageData:canvasContext.getImageData(0, 0,
      canvas.width,canvas.height)});
}
```

Пытаюсь разобраться как работает функция `drawIconAtRotation`. Особенно не врубаюсь что за `ease()` функция.

**UPD2:** Если ещё глубже копать, то я не понимаю, сами действия в `drawIconAtRotation`. Зачем нужно сохранять состояние с помощью `save()`, как работает `translate()`,  `rotate()`. Нашел [статью](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/html5/104718/) на хабре про трансформации, но ещё толком не разобрался с ней =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[HTML Canvas 2D Context](http://dev.w3.org/html5/2dcontext/) — куда уж понятнее??

Задавайте конкретные вопросы.
Но я, лично, не знаю, что там непонятного. Выбираем фигуру, ставим точки. Всё.

---

**UPD1**:
Ну с `drawIconAtRotation` всё понятно уже из названия (а уж тем более из кода) — функция банально отрисовывает иконку, повёрнутой на какой-то угол. Что за функция `ease` — одному автору известно. Геометрия какая-то (у меня по геометрии тройка была) :).

UPD1.1:
Ну Вы поподставляйте разные значения в эту функцию ease. Она, по-моему, так устроена, что выдаёт красивые углы (в радианах) при изменении параметра от 0 до 1. Т.е., реально, *упрощает* вычисления ;).
Можете думать, что эта функция задаёт зависимость угла от времени (т.е. переменная rotation — это, как бы, время, поскольку она меняется линейно). А зависимость подобрана таким образом, чтобы анимация смотрелась хорошо (если присмотреться к формуле, то можно увидеть, что это поворот с косинусоидальной скоростью — т.е. в начале и в конце она маленькая, а в центре — большая… что-то вроде маятника).

---

[The canvas state](http://dev.w3.org/html5/2dcontext/#the-canvas-state)
[Transformations](http://dev.w3.org/html5/2dcontext/#transformations)

**Состояние** — набор аттрибутов контекста: параметры пера и заливки, тени, шрифт, матрицу преобразований. **`save`** сохраняет текущее состояние в условный стек, **`restore`** — восстанавливает из стека последнее состояние.

**`translate`** и **`rotate`** домножают текущую матрицу на матрицу сдвига или поворота соответственно.

Comment: т.е. все операция производятся в стеке?

Comment: Все операции производятся на текущем Вашем canvas'е. Идея в том, что Вы, прежде чем вносить какие-то модификации (например, менять цвет линии), сохраняете предыдущее состояние. Потом рисуете что Вам надо, переключаете там цвета, шрифты, крутите холст и т.п.. Когда закончили, восстанавливаете из стека предыдущее состояние, так что вызвавший Вашу функцию не заметит, что Вы там цвета меняли.